# How to set up personal VoIP server?

Tags: voip, sip, telephony

I'm looking to run my own VoIP server so I can make and record calls and the like. I need to basically bind a phone number to the server and me able to call it and use it as a regular phone. I'm new to VoIP, telephony, and the SIP stack, but I have lots of experience with media servers as a developer. Where should I start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can start with [Asterisk](http://www.asterisk.org/) as the PBX software and [FreePBX](http://www.freepbx.org/) to configure Asterisk using a web interface.

You'll also need a VOIP provider who will give you the ability to place VOIP calls (and receive).
If you want, you can also plug in your PSTN line to receive/place calls using your normal number (but these won't be VOIP calls). For this you'll need a VOIP gateway like Linksys 3102.
If you do both ways, you can receive PSTN calls and use the VOIP line (or lines) to place calls.

You'll also need a softphone to use on your computer or a SipPhone to use like a regular fone or an ATA router to plug your regular phones in it (obs: the Linksys 3102 above can work as the gateway (FXO) and the ATA (FXS)).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this guide: http://www.fredshack.com/docs/asterisk.html

Basically, you'll need some software (Asterisk is very popular) and a PSTN gateway to connect to the standard telephone system.